# How to change state of parent from nested child in React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, state, parent-child

I have 3 nested components in my React app.

1.Parent calling Child1

2.Child1 calling Child2

3.Child2 calling Child3

4.Child3

I want to show a Dialog pop up when user click a button.
The Dialog is in parent and I show it by setting a state variable

`const[showDialog, setShowDialog] = useState(false);`

true/false when user click on the ShowDialog Button

The problem is the button is in Child3.
So how I can make the state change in parent when I click the button in the last child.

Comment: Lift up the state and maintain single source of truth or refer https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Same way as before hooks--pass the method to the child? There are multiple ways it can be done, though.

Comment: I am new to React.. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 - Create a handler function in parent i.e which can toggle the showDialogue state to true or false

```
const showDialogHandler=()=>{ 
     setShowDialog(prevState=> !prevstate) 
}
```

Step 2: pass the handler reference to the child3

```
<Child3 onShowDialog={showDialogHandler} />
```

Step3 : assign that function passed through prop to onClick vent handler.

```
<button onClick={props.onShowDailog}>Show Dialog</button>
```

Comment: Parent not calling Child3.. Call happens in the order I mentioned

Answer (score 1):

use **useContext** ,**useReducer** hook, instead of passing props to the children, you can use **useContext**, **useReducer**  hook to dispatch the action by onclick in the parent and get the true or false response from the context to the chlld component. here is the [codeSandbox exmaple](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-brook-ghkbd?file=/src/childThree.js)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
    // Parent.js
    const Parent = () => {
      const [showDialog, setShowDialog] = useState(false);
      
      return (
        <>
          <div>Show Dialog: {showDialog.toString()}</div>
          <Child3 showDialog={showDialog} setShowDialog={setShowDialog} />
        </>
      );
    };


    // Child3.js
    const Child3 = ({showDialog, setShowDialog}) => {
      
      const handleShowDialog = useCallback(() => {
        setShowDialog(!showDialog)
      }, [setShowDialog, showDialog])

      return (
        <>
          <button onClick={handleShowDialog}>Show Dialog</button>
        </>
      );
    };
```

Comment: Try useCallback() hook in the Child Component

Comment: Parent not calling Child3.. Call happens in the order I mentioned

Comment: Right, So why you couldn't get `Dialog Component` to `Child3`?